# VScode Intellisense shows definition that's not on JSdoc

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, morgan

I'm currently making a project with JS and I happened to use the package [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).
When using it, the VSCode Intellisense shows a documentation that's not compatible with the JSdoc in the index.js file (the only file regarding code).

Example of what it looks like:

[image]

When searching for that in the files, I stumbled upon it in the README file.

I've tried to replicate it without success and would like to know how that is done.

Obs.: I have not checked other text editors.
Obs2.: I disabled every extension, so that's certainly not something done by an extension.

*Thanks in advance!*

Obs.: So, it seems that it's not using the README but rather a TS file downloaded by npm. More on the answer below!

Comment: Are you getting the same message shown in the example?

Comment: Yes, that's an actual print I took. The [index.js file](http://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js) at line 51 states: "Create a logger middleware" but what the intellisense shows is what's written on the readme.

Comment: I think you should provide appropriate arguments to morgan function ex: morgan('tiny')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of rumbling around:

I tried to change what was written in the README and that didn't change what the Intellisense was showing.

So I started looking once again and I found at 'USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\2.9\node_modules\@types\morgan" a file index.d.ts which contained the same descriptions that were in the README. When changing it, the description intellisense gave changed!

So, what's that file? Apparently it's a file on [this repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) used to document Typescript projects but seems like it can be used for JS projects too. Now, when it's that downloaded (I suppose NPM does it) and why VScode uses it instead of the JSdoc are still questions to me.